# unity 3d sprite management for 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing a very basic 2d game with unity 3d.

I have some 2d objets which can have multiple states. For example, imagine Mario: You have small mario, big mario, mario and yoshi. And each mario's state has different sub states (mario running, etc.)

This is exactly what i want to do. So i designed each state in a png file. I have about 50 png files for each object.

Now, i want do integrate this states in my unity project.

I have created a prefab for each object. Each prefab contains its 50 png files.
I also have a C# component attached to the prefab object.
My C# component contains 50 public GameObject properties.
I have linked this properties to the png files.
Then, my C# code tells each png file should be visible or not.

For example:

```
    small_mario_running_1.SetActive(false);
    small_mario_running_2.SetActive(true);

    small_mario_running_1.SetActive(false);
    small_mario_running_2.SetActive(false);
```

Please note mario is just an example.

I have a lot of SetActive calls so i am wondering if there is a best way to do that with unity.

Thanks

Comment: *"So i designed each state in a png file. I have about 50 png files for each object."* You just need **one** *Spritesheet* of your character  animation then you can use Unity's Editor Sprite Editor to extract each tiny sprite so that you can select which sprite to display either through the animation system or script. [This](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/sprite-editor) should get you started.

Comment: Ditch this style of animation and go for skeletal animation. So much easier and can do exactly what you want with less effort... Spine is awesome but costs money. It has an easy to use runtime that integrates with unity and it’s community and developer is active and will help with any issues

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by `Each prefab contains its 50 png files`.

I have only done basic Unity graphics so far, so I'm sure someone here can come up with a more elegant idea, but as a first approach, I would create sprites out of you png files and use 50 public Sprite variables in your C# script, linked to each sprite.  Then dynamically set the `Sprite` for the `Sprite Renderer` on your `mario`.  Assuming your prefab is using a Sprite Renderer.

Something like

```
public Sprite running;
public Sprite bigMario;

if (isRunning)
     GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = running;
else if (isBig)
     GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = bigMario;
```

Comment: That is a good idea but i forget to tell you something: Sometimes i need to show 2 or 3 png at the same time (objects)